# is possible set a table to multiples schemas

Tags: mysql, schema

Is posible set a table to multiples schemas on mysql? For example:

i have two schemas with identical tables:

- schema1.user
- schema2.user

it is possible that when querying schema1.user the information returns the records of schema1.user and schema2.user, without triggers, stored procedures or views?

Comment: If `schema1` and `schema2` are database then, they both can have table with same name and different/same table structure.

Comment: Why, oh why, would you want to do such a thing??

Comment: Because I do not want to duplicate the information in the databases of each winery in my company.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686014/how-to-select-fields-from-different-dbs-with-the-same-table-and-field-name

maybe this would help you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question: No. You can not do that *without triggers, stored procedures or views*

Answer (score 0):

A better way to avoid duplicating your data in every database is to query the `user` table in schema-qualified format.

In other words, even if your default database is schema2 during a given query, you can query the table from schema1:

```
SELECT ... FROM sometable JOIN schema1.user ON ...
```

You can mix qualified and non-qualified syntax in the same query. Any table that doesn't have a schema qualifier is assumed to be in the default schema.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html